# Return multiple labels for a field with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have a function that runs and gets the labels from a lookup table for values stored in a particular table.  When there is 1 value it displays correctly.  However when there is multiple values it only returns the first one.  For example:

```
Lookup table is

| Tel_No| Tel_type |
--------------------
|   1   |  Info    |
|   2   |  Support |
|   3   |  Call    |

Main table is

| TelephoneCalls |
------------------
|  1,3           |
|  3             |
|  1,2,3         |
```

The function I have at the moment which works for matching 1 value is

```
 function getMonitoring($monitoring){
$query = "SELECT Tel_type FROM TelephoneCalls Where Tel_no = '$monitoring'";
$result9 =mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
list($Tel_type) = mysql_fetch_array($result9, MYSQL_NUM);   
    return $Tel_type;
                }
```

How can I get it to list the values like below

```
If 1, 3      then display      Info, Call 
If 3         display      Call
If 1, 2, 3   display      Info, Support, Call
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are the values stored in `TelephoneCalls` actually comma separated numbers? Because it makes this a little harder. Well not really harder, but more inefficient because you then have to query multiple times instead of just once.

Comment: Yes they are all comma separated numbers, eek!

Comment: It's not the end of the world. It just isn't standard. You will have to run another query to get which lookup values apply to those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the comments touched upon it, but you really should change your schema to be more of a many-to-many relationship than using CSV values in the fields.  If you can't this query should work:

```
SELECT telephonecalls, GROUP_CONCAT(tel_type) 
FROM lookup_table
LEFT JOIN main_table ON  FIND_IN_SET(tel_no , replace(TelephoneCalls,' ', '')) > 0 
GROUP BY telephonecalls;

#outputs
+----------------+------------------------+
| telephonecalls | GROUP_CONCAT(tel_type) |
+----------------+------------------------+
| 1,2,3          | Info,Support,Call      |
| 1,3            | Info,Call              |
| 3              | Call                   |
+----------------+------------------------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/194fd/1/0

Comment: I'm so used to using oracle that I forget about some of the built in functions like find_in_set. Still not ideal, but it works.